# how to toggle a BOOL value in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I have the following:

```
for(CTVMenuItem *mi in selected){
  // if showFlag is YES -> NO; if NO -> YES
  mi.showFlag=@(!mi.showFlag);
}
```

but it is not working. Because of common items, I am having a hard time googling it. How would I make a YES become no and a NO become YES?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `showFlag` is of type `BOOL` then it's simply:

```
mi.showFlag = !mi.showFlag;
```

If `showFlag` is actually an `NSNumber` representing a `BOOL`, then you want:

```
mi.showFlag = @(![mi.showFlag boolValue]);
```

Comment: thx - have to wait a few :); got it - that's what I was thinking about. thx for help. If anybody stumbles across this, there's a good post on BOOL here: http://nshipster.com/bool/